# Call derrived class constructor without arguments from main class constructor with arguments

Tags: vb.net, class, constructor

I have a abstract base class and a derrived class. The base class has some members that I want to set based on the derrived class type. But I also have a common constructor for all derrived classes that accept an argument. That common constructor with an argument is repeating code I would like to get rid of.

```
Public MustInherit Class B
    Protected member1 As String
    Protected member2 As String
End Class

Public Class D1 : Inherits B
    Public Sub New()
        Me.member1 = "D1" ' individual code here
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(arg As String)
        Me.New()
        Me.meber2 = arg ' repeating code here, should be moved to base class
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class D2 : Inherits B
    Public Sub New()
        Me.member1 = "D2" ' individual code here
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(arg As String)
        Me.New()
        Me.meber2 = arg ' repeating code here, should be moved to base class
    End Sub
End Class
```

How can I refactor this, so that the derrived constructor without arguments is called, even when invoking the constructor with the argument in the base class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code wouldn't even compile since the member are Private. You could have a Protected method that populates the member.

```
Public MustInherit Class B
    Private member1 As String
    Private member2 As String

    Protected Sub SetMembers(ByVal m1 As String, ByVal m2 As String)
        member1 = m1
        member2 = m2
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class D1 : Inherits B
    Public Sub New()
        Me.New("")
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(arg As String)
        SetMembers("D1", arg)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class D2 : Inherits B
    Public Sub New()
        Me.New("")
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(arg As String)
        SetMembers("D2", arg)
    End Sub
End Class
```

You could change SetMembers to a protected New and call it with MyBase.New(..., ...) if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Why not add a constructor to the base class?

```
Public MustInherit Class B
    Public Sub New(arg As String)
        Me.member2 = arg
    End Sub

    Protected member1 As String
    Protected member2 As String
End Class

Public Class D1 : Inherits B
    Public Sub New(arg As String)
        MyBase.New(arg)
        Me.member1 = "D1"
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class D2 : Inherits B
    Public Sub New(arg As String)
        MyBase.New(arg)
        Me.member1 = "D2"
    End Sub
End Class
```

It doesn't really reduce the duplication, per se, since each derived class still has the line that calls the base constructor, passing it the value, but it does allow you to centrally maintain what it does with that value, and it does force all derived classes to do it.  That way you can never create a derived class where you forget to provide that value.

In fact, if you want to require all derived classes to provide a default value for `member1`, then you could add that as a parameter to the base constructor as well:

```
Public MustInherit Class B
    Public Sub New(member1 As String, member2 As String)
        Me.member1 = member1
        Me.member2 = member2
    End Sub

    Private member1 As String
    Private member2 As String
End Class

Public Class D1 : Inherits B
    Public Sub New(arg As String)
        MyBase.New("D1", arg)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class D2 : Inherits B
    Public Sub New(arg As String)
        MyBase.New("D2", arg)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This will noet set member 1 when you call the base class constructor with the argument

Comment: @FalcoGer I don't understand what you mean, but I updated my answer to hopefully clarify what I was trying to say.